# production webpack main.bundle.js contains full path of files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, frontend, production-environment

Here is piece of text from "main.bundle.js"

`t&&(t.register(u,"ButtonLoaderAtom","/home/ec2-user/<project>/app/atoms/ButtonLoader/index.jsx"),t.register(p,"default","/home/ec2-user/<project>/app/atoms/ButtonLoader/index.jsx"),n(e))}()}).call(t,r(2)(e))}`

**Problem**
"/home/ec2-user//app/atoms/ButtonLoader/index.jsx" the full path name of a file is being displayed in the main.bundle.js in a production build.

**Expectation**
When build is made for production the full path should not be visible.

**Solution**
??

Any help is welcome. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

remove "react-hot-loader/babel", from .babelrc file

Answer (score 0):

Following the lead of @Arup, I had the same problem and set my `.babelrc` to only include `react-hot-loader` in development

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": [...],
  "plugins": [...],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel",]
    }
  }
}
```

And then making sure to set NODE_ENV to production in my webpack build script in `package.json`

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  ...,
  "webpack": "NODE_ENV='production' webpack --mode production",
}
```

Because the `.babelrc` uses the `NODE_ENV` not the webpack `--mode`. When `NODE_ENV` is not set babel defaults to using `env=development`

Then those filepaths were removed from the production bundles while keeping all the `react-hot-loader` stuff in development